# how to get html code inside an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following problem. I want to retrieve some values from a website. This website doesn't reply unless these values are retrieved from a know source. This known source embeds an iframe for showing these values and is publicly available. Embedding this site within my site using an iframe is one option except there are some decisions to be made within this iframe. 
Is it possible to write a class library that loads the page (where this single iframe is returned) getting all elements within this iframe, post some values and get the proper results?

```
Site1/Page ==> Iframe ==>Site2/Page
```

hopefully the question is understandable.

I think that because its possible using a browser and some mouseclicks, it must be possible.

Comment: so you want to do something like "this frame"-->"show source" programmatically?

Comment: yes exactly, but this with the possibility to postback values to this iframe souce (4 dropdownlists)

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3858/How-to-get-the-HTML-source-code-from-an-editable-I) may help you.  In short, it setups a `Hidden` Field and then populates the HTML from the iFrame on the button Submit Click method.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="test"%>
<form id=frmMain method=post runat="server">
    <iframe id=ifrHTML name=ifrHTML runat="server"></iframe>
    <asp:Button id=cmdSend runat="server" Text="Send"></asp:Button>
    <input type=hidden name=hidValue>
</form>
<script>
    //Set the IFRame to Desing Mode.
    ifrHTML.document.designMode = "on";            
</script>

// Code Behind
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cmdSubmit.Attributes.Add("onClick", _
       "document.frmMain.hidValue.value = ifrHTML.document.body.innerHTML;")
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,_
     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click
    Dim strValue As String

    strValue = Request.Form("hidValue")
End Sub
```

- Code from Article

Comment: The Iframe is not within my local domain. So this doesn't seem an option.